# What is the difference between a decision boundary and a hyperplane?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am looking into support vector machines and I am wondering what the difference between the decision boundary and the optimal hyperplane is? They both seem to be described as the line drawn to separate the datapoints.

Comment: How is this a Python question?

Comment: I was using scikit-learn, a python module

Comment: What part of your question was specific to scikit-learn and python, and does not apply to ANY svm? Try to choose precise and fully appropriate tags, such as [tag:svm].

Comment: Furthermore this kind of question is not related to programming but to maths / machine learning concepts. It should therefore better be asked on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The decision boundary for a **linear** support vector machine is an (affine) [hyperplane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane).

For **non-linear kernel** support vector machines, the decision boundary of the support vector machine is not an hyperplane in the original feature space but a non-linear hypersurface (a surface of dimension `n_features - 1`) whose shape depends on the type of kernel.

However, the kernel function can be interpreted as inducing a non-linear mapping from the original feature space to some kernel space. In the kernel space then the decision function of the SVM is an hyperplane. Here is a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3liCbRZPrZA) that gives an intuitive descriptions of the relation between the two for the polynomial kernel.

Comment: Thank you very much, The video was especially helpful!

Answer (score 3):

A [decision boundary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_boundary) is a hypersurface that partitions the underlying vector space into two sets, one for each class. A general hypersurface in a small dimension space is turned into a hyperplane in a space with much larger dimensions.

Hyperplane and decision boundary are equivalent at small dimension space, 'plane' has the meaning of straight and flat, so it is a line or a plane that separate the data sets. When you do a non-linear operation to map your data to a new feature space, the decision boundary is still a hyperplane in that space, but is not a plane any more at the original space.

Comment: So the hyperplane does not decide the separation between classes?

Comment: hyperplane and decision boundary are equivalent at small dimension space, 'plane' has the meaning of straight, so it is a line or a plane that separate the data sets.  When you do a non-linear operation to map your data to a high dimension, the decision boundary is still a hyperplane at that dimension, but is not a plane any more at the original data dimension.

Comment: The size of the dimension is not that important. It's the type of kernel (linear or not) that makes the decision boundary an hyperplane or not.

Comment: @ogrisel thank you for pointing out. I changed the word to 'space' to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

When using kernel functions, the decision boundary will no longer remain a straight line.

(It will still be a hyperplane in a *different, maybe infinite dimensional space*, but this space will not actually be computed or used.)